# Laptop is draining battery when off

Tags: windows-10, battery, power-management, battery-life, xubuntu

I have a cheep Chinese Laptop Jumper Ezbook 3L pro.
I am experiencing the problem with battery drain since several weeks - after one day off the battery is half empty.
I think I first encountered this problem after some windows updates but it didn't affect linux - when shutting of from linux the battery remained 100%.
Now the problem persists on both systems and I don't know further. I am plugging off all usb devices when off. I also resetted bios to it's defaults. I've installed a new ssd a while ago, but it didn't cause the drain in the beginning.
Where else can I look for the cause of the problem

Comment: Are you actually shutting the laptop down from within windows? i.e. going to 'power -> shutdown' and not just closing the lid?

Comment: sure, I do - I even tried shutdown /s /f /t 0

Comment: > _"cheep Chinese Laptop Jumper Ezbook 3L pro"_ - I'd say this is your problem, right here.